# TikZ, multicolumn, and vertical spacing

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

My question is related to the vertical spacing of the objects in the page. I think that in my case TikZ can influence it. Here the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\textheight= 21cm
\textwidth= 14cm
\topmargin=-1cm
\parindent=0cm
\oddsidemargin=1.26cm
\evensidemargin=1.26cm

\begin{document}
\paragraph*{Nice paragraph}

This is some text in the par

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw[<->] (-1,0)--(30,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-1)--(0,6);
    \draw[samples=100,domain=0:30,line cap=round,line join=round] plot(\x,{sqrt(\x)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}\label{fig:funcionRaizCuadradada}

\end{figure}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{small}
\begin{itemize}
\centering
\item[] text una unidad hacia la izquierda, esto es,

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=5mm,y=5mm]
    \draw (0,4) node[above]{\small $y=f(x+1)=\sqrt{x+1}$};
    \draw[<->] (-3,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-1)--(0,4);
    \draw[domain=-1:4.7] plot(\x,{sqrt(\x+1)});
    \end{tikzpicture}

\item[] More Text tres unidades hacia arriba, esto es,

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=5mm,y=5mm]
    \draw (0,6) node[above]{\small $y=f(x)+3=\sqrt{x}+3$};
    \draw[<->] (-1,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-1)--(0,5);
    \draw[domain=0:4] plot(\x,{sqrt(\x)+3});
    \end{tikzpicture}

\item[] Some text de $y=\sqrt{x}$, con respecto al eje $y$, esto es,

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=5mm,y=5mm]
    \draw (0,3) node[above] {\small $y=\sqrt{-x}$};
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(1,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-1)--(0,2);
    \draw[samples=100,domain=-5:0] plot(\x,{sqrt(-\x)});
    \end{tikzpicture}

\columnbreak
\item[] Translation dos unidades hacia la derecha, esto es,

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=5mm,y=5mm]
    \draw (0,4) node[above]{\small $y=f(x-2)=\sqrt{x-2}$};
    \draw[<->] (-1,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-1)--(0,3);
    \draw[samples=100,domain=2:5] plot(\x,{sqrt(\x-2)});
    \end{tikzpicture}

\item[] Reflection de $y=\sqrt{x}$, con respecto al eje $x$, esto es,

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=5mm,y=5mm]
    \draw[<->] (-1,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-3)--(0,1);
    \draw[samples=100,domain=0:5] plot(\x,{-sqrt(\x)});
    \draw (0,1) node[above] {\small $y=-\sqrt{x}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\item[] Reflection de $y=\sqrt{x+1}$, con respecto al eje $x$, esto es,

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=5mm,y=5mm]
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(1,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-1)--(0,3);
    \draw[samples=100,domain=-5.7:-1] plot(\x,{sqrt(-\x-1)});
    \draw (0,4) node[above]{\small $y=\sqrt{-x-1}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{itemize}
\end{small}
\end{multicols}

\newpage
\paragraph*{Bad paragraph}

There exist som text to put here\enlargethispage*{20cm}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \clip (-6,-6) rectangle (6,6);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{1/\x});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}\label{fig:funcionRacional}
\end{figure}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{small}
\begin{itemize}
\centering
\item[] Traslation una unidad hacia la izquierda, esto es,

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above]{\small $y=f(x+1)=\dfrac{1}{x+1}$};
    \clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{1/(\x+1)});
    \draw[dotted] (-1,-5)--(-1,5);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\item[] Traslation $\frac{3}{2}$ hacia arriba, esto es,

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above]{\small $y=f(x)+\dfrac{3}{2}=\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{3}{2}$};
    \clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{(1/\x)+1.5});
    \draw[dotted] (-5,1.5)--(5,1.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\item[] Reflection de $y=\frac{1}{x}$, esto es,

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above]{\small $y=-\dfrac{1}{x}$};
    \clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{-(1/\x)});
    \end{tikzpicture}

\columnbreak    
\item[] Traslation una unidad hacia la derecha, esto es,

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above] {\small $y=\dfrac{1}{x-1}$};
    \clip (-5,-5)rectangle(5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{1/((\x)-1)});
    \draw[dotted] (1,-5)--(1,5);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\item[] Traslation $\frac{3}{2}$ hacia abajo, esto es,

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above]{\small $y=f(x)-\dfrac{3}{2}=\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{3}{2}$};
    \clip (-5,-5)rectangle(5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{(1/(\x))-1.5});
    \draw[dotted] (-5,-1.5)--(5,-1.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\item[] Traslation horizontal y vertical, elongation de $y=\frac{1}{x}$, esto es,

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above]{\small $y=f(x)-\dfrac{3}{2}=\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{3}{2}$};
    \clip (-5,-5)rectangle(5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{(3/((\x)-2))+1});
    \draw[dotted] (1,-5)--(1,5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{itemize}
\end{small}
\end{multicols}\pagebreak
\end{document}
```

The first page looks like this:

[image]

It is that I want. But the next pages looks like:

[image]

it is an unpleasant result. That I want is two columns each of them with three images in the same page of the Figure 2. In order to do this I have tried `\enlargethispage*` but it don't works, as you can see there is a lot of wasted vertical space. The only difference between the first page and the next, is that in the second one I use `\clip` command in the plots. I suspect that this causes the vertical space can not be stretched. How can I do it better?

Comment: Please, provide a complete MWE, i.e., from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. This way nobody need to guess your preamble with all packages and macros. In any case, you can distribute your figures with a two columns `tabular` instead of using `multicols`.

Comment: I second tabular. This way you can get around some flow problems.

Comment: The problem is not that you used `clip` on your second page, but instead that the topmost picture is simply slightly taller than the one on your first page. If you use `\clip (-5,-4) rectangle (5,5);` in that picture, everything will snap back into place, even without using `enlargethispage`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way that produces better results is to place each figure in a `minipage` (and the associated text).  This will keep the text and the figure from separating across columns:

[image]

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\textheight= 21cm
\textwidth= 14cm
\topmargin=-1cm
\parindent=0cm
\oddsidemargin=1.26cm
\evensidemargin=1.26cm

\begin{document}
\paragraph*{Nice paragraph}

This is some text in the par

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw[<->] (-1,0)--(30,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-1)--(0,6);
    \draw[samples=100,domain=0:30,line cap=round,line join=round] plot(\x,{sqrt(\x)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}\label{fig:funcionRaizCuadradada}
\end{figure}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{small}
\begin{itemize}
%\centering
\item[] 
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\raggedright
text una unidad hacia la izquierda, esto es,
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=5mm,y=5mm]
    \draw (0,4) node[above]{\small $y=f(x+1)=\sqrt{x+1}$};
    \draw[<->] (-3,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-1)--(0,4);
    \draw[domain=-1:4.7,red] plot(\x,{sqrt(\x+1)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\item[] 
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
More Text tres unidades hacia arriba, esto es,

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=5mm,y=5mm]
    \draw (0,6) node[above]{\small $y=f(x)+3=\sqrt{x}+3$};
    \draw[<->] (-1,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-1)--(0,5);
    \draw[domain=0:4] plot(\x,{sqrt(\x)+3});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\item[] 
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
Some text de $y=\sqrt{x}$, con respecto al eje $y$, esto es,

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=5mm,y=5mm]
    \draw (0,3) node[above] {\small $y=\sqrt{-x}$};
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(1,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-1)--(0,2);
    \draw[samples=100,domain=-5:0] plot(\x,{sqrt(-\x)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\columnbreak
\item[] 
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
Translation dos unidades hacia la derecha, esto es,

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=5mm,y=5mm]
    \draw (0,4) node[above]{\small $y=f(x-2)=\sqrt{x-2}$};
    \draw[<->] (-1,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-1)--(0,3);
    \draw[samples=100,domain=2:5] plot(\x,{sqrt(\x-2)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\item[] 
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
Reflection de $y=\sqrt{x}$, con respecto al eje $x$, esto es,

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=5mm,y=5mm]
    \draw[<->] (-1,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-3)--(0,1);
    \draw[samples=100,domain=0:5] plot(\x,{-sqrt(\x)});
    \draw (0,1) node[above] {\small $y=-\sqrt{x}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\item[] 
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
Reflection de $y=\sqrt{x+1}$, con respecto al eje $x$, esto es,

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=5mm,y=5mm]
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(1,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-1)--(0,3);
    \draw[samples=100,domain=-5.7:-1] plot(\x,{sqrt(-\x-1)});
    \draw (0,4) node[above]{\small $y=\sqrt{-x-1}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{itemize}
\end{small}
\end{multicols}

\newpage
\paragraph*{Bad paragraph}

There exist som text to put here\enlargethispage*{20cm}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \clip (-6,-6) rectangle (6,6);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{1/\x});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}\label{fig:funcionRacional}
\end{figure}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{small}
\begin{itemize}
\centering
\item[] 
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
Traslation una unidad hacia la izquierda, esto es,

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above]{\small $y=f(x+1)=\dfrac{1}{x+1}$};
    \clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100,blue] plot(\x,{1/(\x+1)});
    \draw[dotted] (-1,-5)--(-1,5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\item[] 
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
Traslation $\frac{3}{2}$ hacia arriba, esto es,

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above]{\small $y=f(x)+\dfrac{3}{2}=\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{3}{2}$};
    \clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100,green] plot(\x,{(1/\x)+1.5});
    \draw[dotted] (-5,1.5)--(5,1.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\item[] 
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
Reflection de $y=\frac{1}{x}$, esto es,

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above]{\small $y=-\dfrac{1}{x}$};
    \clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100,orange] plot(\x,{-(1/\x)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\columnbreak    
\item[] 
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
Traslation una unidad hacia la derecha, esto es,

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above] {\small $y=\dfrac{1}{x-1}$};
    \clip (-5,-5)rectangle(5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100,cyan] plot(\x,{1/((\x)-1)});
    \draw[dotted] (1,-5)--(1,5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\item[] 
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
Traslation $\frac{3}{2}$ hacia abajo, esto es,

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above]{\small $y=f(x)-\dfrac{3}{2}=\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{3}{2}$};
    \clip (-5,-5)rectangle(5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100,violet] plot(\x,{(1/(\x))-1.5});
    \draw[dotted] (-5,-1.5)--(5,-1.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\item[]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
Traslation horizontal y vertical, elongation de $y=\frac{1}{x}$, esto es,

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above]{\small $y=f(x)-\dfrac{3}{2}=\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{3}{2}$};
    \clip (-5,-5)rectangle(5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{(3/((\x)-2))+1});
    \draw[dotted] (1,-5)--(1,5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{itemize}
\end{small}
\end{multicols}\pagebreak
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to keep all the seven figures together, I recommend using one `minipage` (page breaks are not allowed inside `minipage`s) for the seven elements; the six figures can be placed using six inner `minipage`s; in this way, you don't have to use a `multicols` environment nor a list:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\textheight= 21cm
\textwidth= 14cm
\topmargin=-1cm
\parindent=0cm
\oddsidemargin=1.26cm
\evensidemargin=1.26cm

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
There exist some text to put here

{   \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \clip (-6,-6) rectangle (6,6);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{1/\x});
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \captionof{figure}{}
  \label{fig:funcionRacional}
}

  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \raggedright
    Traslation una unidad hacia la izquierda, esto es,\par
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above]{\small $y=f(x+1)=\dfrac{1}{x+1}$};
    \clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{1/(\x+1)});
    \draw[dotted] (-1,-5)--(-1,5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
  \raggedright
  Traslation una unidad hacia la derecha, esto es,\par
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above] {\small $y=\dfrac{1}{x-1}$};
    \clip (-5,-5)rectangle(5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{1/((\x)-1)});
    \draw[dotted] (1,-5)--(1,5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage}\\[2ex]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
  \raggedright
  Traslation $\frac{3}{2}$ hacia arriba, esto es,\par
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above]{\small $y=f(x)+\dfrac{3}{2}=\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{3}{2}$};
    \clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{(1/\x)+1.5});
    \draw[dotted] (-5,1.5)--(5,1.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
  \raggedright
  Traslation $\frac{3}{2}$ hacia abajo, esto es,\par
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above]{\small $y=f(x)-\dfrac{3}{2}=\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{3}{2}$};
    \clip (-5,-5)rectangle(5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{(1/(\x))-1.5});
    \draw[dotted] (-5,-1.5)--(5,-1.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage}\\[2ex]
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}
      \raggedright
  Reflection de $y=\frac{1}{x}$, esto es,\par
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above]{\small $y=-\dfrac{1}{x}$};
    \clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{-(1/\x)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}
  \raggedright
  Traslation horizontal y vertical, elongation de $y=\frac{1}{x}$, esto es,\par
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above]{\small $y=f(x)-\dfrac{3}{2}=\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{3}{2}$};
    \clip (-5,-5)rectangle(5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{(3/((\x)-2))+1});
    \draw[dotted] (1,-5)--(1,5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another, perhaps simpler, option would be to use one `tabular` environment for the seven elements (`tabular` also doesn't admit page breaks); the caption for the figure was obtained with `\captionof` provided by the `caption` package. Using this approach, again, there's no need for a `multicols` environment nor a list:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\textheight= 21cm
\textwidth= 14cm
\topmargin=-1cm
\parindent=0cm
\oddsidemargin=1.26cm
\evensidemargin=1.26cm

\begin{document}

There exist some text to put here

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{%
  @{}>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}
  >{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}
  \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}{
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \clip (-6,-6) rectangle (6,6);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{1/\x});
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \captionof{figure}{}
  \label{fig:funcionRacional}
  }\tabularnewline
%
    Traslation una unidad hacia la izquierda, esto es,\par
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above]{\small $y=f(x+1)=\dfrac{1}{x+1}$};
    \clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{1/(\x+1)});
    \draw[dotted] (-1,-5)--(-1,5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
&
  Traslation una unidad hacia la derecha, esto es,\par
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above] {\small $y=\dfrac{1}{x-1}$};
    \clip (-5,-5)rectangle(5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{1/((\x)-1)});
    \draw[dotted] (1,-5)--(1,5);
    \end{tikzpicture} \tabularnewline
%
  Traslation $\frac{3}{2}$ hacia arriba, esto es,\par
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above]{\small $y=f(x)+\dfrac{3}{2}=\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{3}{2}$};
    \clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{(1/\x)+1.5});
    \draw[dotted] (-5,1.5)--(5,1.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
&
  Traslation $\frac{3}{2}$ hacia abajo, esto es,\par
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above]{\small $y=f(x)-\dfrac{3}{2}=\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{3}{2}$};
    \clip (-5,-5)rectangle(5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{(1/(\x))-1.5});
    \draw[dotted] (-5,-1.5)--(5,-1.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}\tabularnewline
%
  Reflection de $y=\frac{1}{x}$, esto es,\par
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above]{\small $y=-\dfrac{1}{x}$};
    \clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{-(1/\x)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
&
  Traslation horizontal y vertical, elongation de $y=\frac{1}{x}$, esto es,\par
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,x=3mm,y=3mm]
    \draw (0,5) node[above]{\small $y=f(x)-\dfrac{3}{2}=\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{3}{2}$};
    \clip (-5,-5)rectangle(5,5);
    \draw[<->] (-5,0)--(5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5)--(0,5);
    \draw[samples=100] plot(\x,{(3/((\x)-2))+1});
    \draw[dotted] (1,-5)--(1,5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

As a final recommendation, the changes to the lengths `\textheight`, `\textwidth`, etc. are better done with the help of the [geometry](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package.

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo. Just a little question: is a good practice to avoid the use of too many nested environments? Just curiosity.

Comment: @leo: it depends on the meaning of "too many". Well used, nesting environments is an advantage; think, for example, of the list-like environments, or `tabular` and `minipage`. Being able to nest those environments is really useful and, in some cases, required (as in the case of the list-like environments). Of course, abusing nesting might not be good.